# Stuck on PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a page that allows users to change their password and email. All of it works but for some reason when I just want to change my email I also get the field *Current Password is incorrect*. 
The email itself changes in the database but this shows up, I've obviously validated that it shwos up but I am unsure of how to get around to write a new query that will ignore the previous queries if only the email is changed.

[image]

My code:

```
<title>Honda |</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />



<?php
session_start();



$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

    echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2><div class="search12"><h2><a href="index2.php">Home</a></h2></p></div></div>';


    if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))
    {
        //user is logged in

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //start changing password
            //check fields

            $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
            $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
            $email = $_POST['email'];


            $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


            //check password against db
            include('../includes/config.php');

            $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username'") or die ("change password failed");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
            $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

            //check passwords
            if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
            {

                if (isset($_POST['repeatnewpassword']) AND isset($_POST['newpassword']) AND $_POST['newpassword'] != '') {
                    if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                    {
                        $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
                        echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed!</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
                    }
                    else {echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) dont match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}

                }


            }
            else {echo "<div class='results'>current password doesnt match</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br>Try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}


            if (isset($_POST['email']) AND $_POST['email'] != '') {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   username='$username'");
                echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Your email has been changed</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
            }}


        else
        {

            echo"
        <form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
        <label>Current Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword'><p>
        <label>New Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
        <label>Repeat New Password:</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
        <label>Email:</label> <input type='email'  name='email'><p>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
        <h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2>
        </form>
        ";


        }}
    else
        die ("You must be logged in to change your password");


    ?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Comment: Mysql is deprecated please consider upgrading to mysqli

Comment: @Abkarino Thanks for letting me know, but I don't plan to put this website live. I would use PDO if I were to make it live. Thanks

Comment: can a user change both email and password at the same time ?

Comment: Do you check to see if anything was put in the new and old password fields? If there was nothing, assume the user isn't updating their password and you can skip over that entire section of code.

Comment: @Abkarino Yes, a user can change both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You're checking that the post values are set for the password (which they always will be, because that form element will always be submitted). Instead of simplychecking if those vaues are set, make sure thay're not empty. use empty() Also, when making comparisons don't use the word "AND" use the and operator "&&".

```
        if (!empty($_POST['repeatnewpassword']) && !empty($_POST['newpassword'])) {
            if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
            {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
                echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed!</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
            }
            else {echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) dont match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}

        }
```

I'm looking at the wrong chunk of code. The above advice is good advice, but your problem is here:

If the password fields are empty then these will never be the same, so `if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)` will always evaluate false.

Try

```
if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb && !empty($_POST['oldpassword']))
```

Comment: Same thing :( :(! 'current password doesnt match'

Comment: Using `empty()` to check is something is not filled is bad.

Comment: @SalmanA That sounds like a personal opinion, care to back it up with facts?

Comment: Enter `0` as your password and see what happens.

Comment: @Ariana The reason you're still getting that error is because you're not entering your current password. The way your script is written the current password must always match even if you're only changing the username. That's actually a good idea,  but you do need to at least enter the current password.

Comment: @Adelphia Is there anyway around that?

Comment: Which? Using empty or entering your password? @Ariana

Comment: @Adelphia Lets say you can't change the email without entering the password? Is that possible

Comment: You'd have to post the chunk of code that actually changes the username

Comment: Anything's possible ;) At this point you may want to consider asking that as a separate question though

Comment: @Adelphia I'm just stuck :( I would really like just that to work atleast

Answer (score -1):

Your query is probably spitting out an array. Try doing `print_r($row)` and examining the output. I have a feeling you're getting an associative array here and need to access the old password differently. Put the `print_r` after this line:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
```

The answer is probably `$row[0]['password'];`

Also, don't use `MD5` for hashing, use [Scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) or something like that with [salt and maybe pepper](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough).